# how to migrate a large database to new server

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to migrate my database from my old server to my new server. I have a very big problem by transferring the database because I have a large database with 5gb. I tried to transfer using `c panel transfer` but I can't it is not useful. I need a more efficient way to transfer the data.

Can anyone guide me with the full transfer details? How to transfer using import and export or do I need to use any other method?

MySQL type is MyISAM and size is 5gb.

Comment: Talk about "not useful".

Comment: Relevent question from friends over at [DBA Stackexchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/174/how-can-i-move-a-database-from-one-server-to-another).

Comment: 5GB big? I wish my databases were so tiny. 5GB is less than the RAM I have on my current phone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try command line if you have access to SSH for both server as command below if not you can try using Navicat application to sync databases

**SSH commands**
Take mysqldump of database
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html

create tar ball of SQL dump file using

```
tar -zcvf db.tar.gz db.sql
```

now upload tar.gz file to other server using scp command

```
scp -Cp db.gz {username}@{server}:{path}
```

now login on other server using SSH
Untar file using linux cmd

```
tar -zxvf db.tar.gz
```

import to database
    mysql -u{username} -p  {database} < db.sql

Please have a look at syntax though syntax will work but consider this as direction only
Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

For large databases I would suggest to use mysqldump if you have SSH access to the server.

From the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/copying-databases.html):

Use `mysqldump --help` to see what options are available.

The easiest (although not the fastest) way to move a database between two machines is to run the following commands on the machine on which the database is located:

```
shell> mysqladmin -h 'other_hostname' create db_name
shell> mysqldump db_name | mysql -h 'other_hostname' db_name
```

If you want to copy a database from a remote machine over a slow network, you can use these commands:

```
shell> mysqladmin create db_name
shell> mysqldump -h 'other_hostname' --compress db_name | mysql db_name
```

You can also store the dump in a file, transfer the file to the target machine, and then load the file into the database there. For example, you can dump a database to a compressed file on the source machine like this:

```
shell> mysqldump --quick db_name | gzip > db_name.gz
```

Transfer the file containing the database contents to the target machine and run these commands there:

```
shell> mysqladmin create db_name
shell> gunzip < db_name.gz | mysql db_name
```

You can also use mysqldump and mysqlimport to transfer the database. For large tables, this is much faster than simply using mysqldump. In the following commands, DUMPDIR represents the full path name of the directory you use to store the output from mysqldump.

First, create the directory for the output files and dump the database:

```
shell> mkdir DUMPDIR
shell> mysqldump --tab=DUMPDIR db_name
```

Then transfer the files in the DUMPDIR directory to some corresponding directory on the target machine and load the files into MySQL there:

```
shell> mysqladmin create db_name           # create database
shell> cat DUMPDIR/*.sql | mysql db_name   # create tables in database
shell> mysqlimport db_name DUMPDIR/*.txt   # load data into tables
```

Do not forget to copy the mysql database because that is where the grant tables are stored. You might have to run commands as the MySQL root user on the new machine until you have the mysql database in place.

After you import the mysql database on the new machine, execute `mysqladmin flush-privileges` so that the server reloads the grant table information.